# Understanding members of Symbol - function constructor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

On console,

```
#> window.Symbol
ƒ Symbol() { [native code] }
```

says that `window.Symbol` is a name of a function constructor(*f*). This also has a prototypical relation(`__proto__`) with `Function.prototype`

```
#> window.Symbol.apply
ƒ apply() { [native code] }
```

says that, `apply` is a name of a member function(*f*) of `Function.prototype` accessible as `Symbol.apply` due to prototypical relation(`__proto__`).

---

On saying,

```
#> Object.prototype.toString.call(Symbol.iterator)
"[object Symbol]"

#> window.Symbol.iterator
Symbol(Symbol.iterator)
```

What does `Symbol(Symbol.iterator)` mean? Could not get this syntax

Comment: Do you have a specific question that's not answered here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator ?

Comment: Are you asking what `Symbol.iterator` is?

Comment: `Symbol` is a function. All functions have `Function.prototype` as their parent prototype (by default). All functions also have an `.apply` method which (since it is a method) is itself a function. All of this is irrelevant to `Symbol` because they could be said of almost any function.

Comment: The first two-thirds of your question seems unrelated to what you're asking.

Comment: @MatusDubrava As below answer says, `Symbol` is a function but not constructor, `iterator` is a static member of `Symbol` function, which is fine to say `Symbol.iterator`. What does syntax `Symbol(Symbol.iterator)` mean?

Comment: The string value for any symbol is `Symbol(theSymbol'sKey)`. In the case of `Symbol.iterator` that key is `"Symbol.iterator"`. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toString) you go. It's just the way Symbol's `toString()` is implemented (and in turn gets printed in console), not any special syntax.

Answer (score 2):

`Symbol.iterator` is one of many [well-known Symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol#Well-known_symbols).

> says that window.Symbol is a name of a function constructor(f).

Symbol is not a constructor; it must be called without `new`. It is a function though, and functions can have properties.

`Symbol.iterator` is just a reference to a particular symbol, not much different than doing this to make `X.first` refer to a particular instance of `X`:

```js
function X ( ) {
    this.foo = 'bar';
}

X.first = new X;

console.log( X.first );
```